# Tag synonym [iAd] and [iAds]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

Can someone with the correct privileges create a tag synonym for the tags [iad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iad) and [iads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iads). They refer to the same topic and have nearly exact wiki definitions.

[iad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iad) Excerpt from wiki:

> iAd is a mobile advertising platform developed by Apple Inc. for its line of mobile devices running iOS, allowing third-party developers to directly embed advertisements into their applications.

[iads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iads) Excerpt from wiki:

> iAd is a mobile advertising platform developed by Apple Inc. for its iPhone, iPod Touch, and iPad line of mobile devices allowing third-party developers to directly embed advertisements into their applications.

It seems that tag synonyms take awhile to get approved from what I've read here on meta. Should I in the meantime edit and retag questions that use [iads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iads) to use the more popular and correct tag [iad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iad)? Would that be detrimental to the site?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Done. I made [iads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iads) a synonym of the main [iad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iad), and cleaned up a few questions that were improperly tagged.

Comment: What about the final question? Is there any point in suggesting edits to re-tag posts?

Comment: @NisseEngström - I think the easiest way to make sure this won't keep coming up is the synonym. Edits would only take care of the questions we have now with the other tag, not future ones. Now that the synonym is there, there's not a great need to edit these. I took care of a few that were mis-tagged to begin with, but that was it.